# Does Mesos Overwrite Hadoop Memory Settings?

Tags: hadoop, memory-management, mesos, mapper, reducers

My company runs hadoop on mesos, and I’m new to mesos.  The current limiting rate of the hadoop application I’m in charge of is the speed of reducer tasks, so I was hoping to play around with mesos and hadoop memory settings to speed up the reducer.

Unfortunately, I don’t understand the relationship between hadoop memory settings and mesos memory configuration, and I suspect that mesos may be overriding some of my hadoop memory settings.

Is changing the value of mapreduce.reduce.java.opts or  mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb (in /etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml) affected by mesos?  Does mesos limit the amount of memory that I can allocate to the reducer?

If so, where are the config files in mesos so I can change those settings?

### Thanks!

9/30/2015 Update:

The file at https://github.com/mesos/hadoop/blob/master/configuration.md lists parameters that you can put in your mapred-site.xml file.

I'm still not sure how those parameters affect the memory-associated hadoop configuration parameters in mapred-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is described in the respective GitHub repo [mesos/hadoop](https://github.com/mesos/hadoop#configure).

Comment: Hi Michael, are you referring specifically to the information at https://github.com/mesos/hadoop/blob/master/configuration.md ?  I wasn't finding that particularly helpful.  Can you explain what parameter or what file you're referring to?  Thanks.